# CSS+JAVASCRIPT | A hidden button move visibility button

Tags: javascript, css

I use 2 buttons. I need to hidden a button and see the other button (visibility button) centered. But the problem is that the hidden button occupy space and the other button isn´t centered.
Case B: The button1 should be centered, but there is a button2 hidden that ocuppy space and move button1 to left.
It should be that we can see in case C and D. (The visibility button centered).

Why?

Javascript (B):

```
document.getElementById('button1').style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('button2').style.visibility=hidden';
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: use display instead of visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using visibility = 'hidden' the element will not be visible but it will render and will take space.

Instead use style="display:none" because the element will not be rendered at all and will not take space.